# Initializing filter with values from application.properties

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0

I want to secure my REST API (jersey2) based on IP addresses, but without having the trouble of Spring Security and so on. I simply need to whitelist a few IPs that are granted full access rights.

To implement this, I thought of putting the IPs into the application.properties and enforcing the restriction using a Filter. This works perfectly fine, when using an embedded Jetty server, but fails when deploying the application as war on Tomcat.

I tried to read the properties both in the Filter constructor and in the init-method (only the constructor example shown below in the snippet). Nevertheless both lead to a NullPointerException when accessing the class field (String ips), which store the IPs. Also using the Enviroment variable does not seem to help.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
@Component("RestAuthFilter")
public class RestAuthFilter implements Filter {

    private String ips;

    public RestAuthFilter() {
        try {
            final Properties p;
            final InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
            p = new Properties();
            p.load(input);
            ips = p.getProperty("whitelist.rest.ips");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            ips = "127.0.0.1";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res,
                     final FilterChain chain) throws ServletException,     IOException {

        final List<String> allowedIPs = Arrays.asList(ips.split("[,]"));

        if(!allowedIPs.contains(req.getRemoteAddr())) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) res).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Not allowed to use REST API!");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
       }
    }

    @Override
   public void destroy() {
   }
```

}

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.RestAuthFilter.doFilter(RestAuthFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: How are you using "Enviroment variable" method, and where is your application.properties located when deployed as war?

Comment: @user2264997 application.properties is located under `src/main/resources/` and therefore also in the classpath. This file additionally contains the credentials for the database and seems to work fine. Concerning to the Environment variable I am refering to `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`, which I included using DI, something like `@Autowired Environment env` as class member and I tried to use the according getProperties-method

Comment: In the WAR it is in  `WEB-INF/classes` of course ...

Comment: Do you use Maven for create WAR-file?

Comment: I don't do Spring, but that `@Component` on a filter looks weird (even if I were just using Java EE standard CDI instead of Spring). Is it why you aren't performing initialization just in `init()` method? Can you assure that the c'tor is really invoked on the concrete instance (and is thus not being proxied), and that the `p.getProperty("whitelist.rest.ips");` didn't simply return `null`? Why not just a normal `@WebFilter`, after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Spring Boot and your setup is pretty standard, I would stick to using PropertySource (via @Value or Environment) to load the IPs from application.properties. Having said that, and noticing your comment about using Environment ...

> Concerning to the Environment variable I am refering to
>   org.springframework.core.env.Environment, which I included using DI,
>   something like @Autowired Environment env as class member

You can't inject it as a class member and have your initialization in the constructor, you'll run into scoping issue -- the Environment will not be set when the constructor is called. You need to inject the Environment via constructor not as a class member, for example:

```
@Component("RestAuthFilter")
public class RestAuthFilter implements Filter {

  private final List<String> restClientIps;

  @Autowired
  public RestAuthFilter(Environment env) {
    String restClientIpsProperty = env.getRequiredProperty("whitelist.rest.ips");
    restClientIps = // parse/split from restClientIpsProperty
  }
  ...
}
```